# Looking for a loop solution to copy from master ws to every empty worksheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely at a loss here. Not good enough to even attempt coding this yet. Here is what I am hoping to achieve:

In a workbook I have a macro that pulls data from a CSV file and copies it into "Master Data" worksheet and again into "Temp" worksheet at the same time formatting headers in "Temp" to what I require (rows A and B which will need to stay constant throughout all worksheets. This has gone (with some help from yourselves) well. The macro then creates x amount of empty sheets based on input.box . Now I need to code two things:

1. Copy the first two rows from "Temp" worksheet into all empty worksheets created by input.box (number not determined as it is not gonna be constant)
2. Cut and Paste range of data from row C until the end of data in "Temp" worksheet row-by-row to all worksheets created by input.box so that row C is copied to first empty row in sheet2, row D to first empty row in sheet3 and so on until no more data to be cut and pasted. It will need to loop through all sheets in workbook that have default names (sheet2, sheet3 and so on). There will not be more than 10 such sheets in the workbook.

I honestly do not even know where to begin, I am not good in loops, especially ones that seem so complicated as this one.

Here is what I managed to put together so far. Just a couple of modules that get me to the point of writing the above. I realize my code is not elegant, parts of it are not my own either as I already asked for help here and received it.

```
Sub Import_CSV_File()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", ,
  "Please select .csv file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile,     
Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
 .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
 .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
 .Refresh
ActiveSheet.Name = "Master Data"
Worksheets("Master Data").Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete

End With
End Sub

Sub Sort_Data_by_Price_Descending()
Columns("A:Q").Sort key1:=Range("G:G"), order1:=xlDescending,     
Header:=xlYes
End Sub

Sub Create_Sheet_and_Copy_Master_Data()

Dim ws As Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Temp"
    Sheets("Master Data").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Temp").Range("A1")
    Range("A1:Z1") = Array("Code", "Carrier", "Operator", "CardNo", "ExpDate", "Comment1", "OrdAmount", "OrdNo", "OrdDate", "CustNo", "DOB", "Name", "Add1", "Add2", "Add3", " ", " ", " ", "Redline", "ISS", "CCN", "Add Links", "AVS", "Referrals", "Comments", "Verified?")
    Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
    CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1:K1") = Array("Batch No.", " ", "Carrier", " ", "Orders", " ", "Start Time", " ", "End Time", " ", "Batch ID")
End With
End Sub

Sub AddSheets_via_Input_Box()

Dim numberOfSheets As Integer
numberOfSheets = CInt(Trim$(InputBox("...how many people are working Fraud Today?", "Tell me…", 1)))
If IsNumeric(numberOfSheets) Then
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets("Temp"), Count:=numberOfSheets
End With
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid parameter supplied - use numbers only"
End If
```

Comment: Is there a max column length to your data? Or does this vary

Comment: The number of columns is maximum @ 25 except 1st row which is 11 but copying 14 empty cells in there is perfectly fine so 25 is the maximum number of columns in all rows in this wb.

Comment: Now this is not what you asked though, sorry. Column Length varies as data in them is not uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your first ask. It does not need to know the number captured by the input box. It will loop through all sheets while skipping `Master Data` and `Temp`.

```
Sub Top2Rows()

Dim Temp As Worksheet: Set Temp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
Temp.Range("A1:Z2").Copy
    If ws.Name <> "Temp" And ws.Name <> "Master Data" Then
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

---

Hopefully you can figure out how to apply similar logic to your next sheets. What I would do (if I understand the ask for #2 correctly) is:

1. Determine how many rows you have
2. Determine how many target sheets you have (`ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 2`)
3. Create some loops to add a ranges to a `Union` (number of loops determined by how many sheets target sheets you have)
4. Copy/Paste the `Union.EntireRow` of cells rather doing this row by row.

You could also create a numbering system and use a filter to do the same thing. Either way, your'e going to want to avoid doing this row by row.

Good luck!

Comment: The code you created works exactly right. I am going to try coding the second part somehow but there are a few tricky spots. First of all I will have to implement a way for the macro to check how many sheets I have since I the number will vary day to day anywhere from 1 to 10 (one per person working). Second

Comment: Second I unfortunately have to copy it row by row as the data is arranged in such a way it would be unfair to people processing those sheets to just divide rows by number of sheets and copy paste whole blocks into them. Since data is arranged in a descending order by value (has to be that way) the loop will have to give each person a somewhat equal workload.

Comment: You can make a loop to go row by row. You can find out how many sheets with the bit of code I provided on step 2 (`ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 2`) I am taking away 2 to discount for the `Master Data` and `Temp` worksheet

Comment: You are right, you provided all the tools I need actually. Thanks for that last hint, I just realized I did not fully understand this bit of code. (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 2). Thank you.